# Julia - Mathematical operators and Array{Union{Float64, Missing}}

Tags: julia

Converting some code from `v0.6.4` to `v1.0.1`, I noticed a strange behaviour of basic mathematic operators with `Array{Union{Float64, Missing}}` in `v0.6.4`. I am not sure this issue is still there for `v0.7+`. I would like to find a solution which works for `v0.6.4`, so that I can compare the output of my code with its current working version.

Suppose I have,

```
using Missings;
A = Array{Union{Float64, Missing}}([2.0 1.0 missing]);
B = [2.0 1.0 0.5];
```

In `v0.6.4`, the sum `A+B` and the element-wise sum `A.+B` give an output matrix which is `Array{Any,2}`. I was expecting an `Array{Union{Float64, Missing},2}`, since the first argument of the sum has this type. Same applies to other basic mathematical operations.

I found an ugly workaround for `A+B`, but not for the element-wise sum `A.+B`. What would you suggest to do in order to get the correct type for both operations (and similar - e.g., `A.-B`)?

Comment: In Julia 1.0 they both give the same result of type `Array{Union{Missing, Float64},2}`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what I could do to get the same output in `v0.6.4`?

Comment: I do not have v0.6.4 any more but probably you can handle this by adding some promotion rules. You can find the rules used in Julia 1.0 in missing.jl file in Base. It should be possible to backport them.

Comment: If it were easy for addition (or broadcast addition) between `Array{Union{Float64,Missing},2}` and `Array{Float64,2}` to return `Array{Union{Float64,Missing},2}` in v0.6, then the devs would have probably implemented it in v0.6. It is telling that this behaviour was not implemented until v0.7. What I'm saying is that you might be opening a huge can of worms trying to backport this behaviour to v0.6 that drains an enormous amount of your time. Maybe you could get away with just wrapping the output of any addition/subtraction operations with a `convert` call in the code you want to test?

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest converting your code from v0.6.4 to v0.7, rather than v1.0.1. If it runs in v0.7, it'll run in v1.0.1, but v0.7 has all those nice deprecation warnings that makes the job vastly easier.

Comment: You don't need the complicated type conversion. Just write `A = [2.0, 1.0, missing]`, and you'll get a `Vector{Union{Missing, Float64}}`. At least in v.1.0.

Comment: And if you're concerned with performance, this is faster: `Union{Float64, Missing}[2.0, 1.0, missing]`.

Comment: Thank you, this discussion was very helpful. My post was not clear on that, but I am actually converting to 0.7 first, in order to get all the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (relatively) simple solution to handle `A.+B`. I defined an ad-hoc broadcast method for the sum operator that converts the output of `Base.Broadcast.broadcast_c` into a `Array{Union{T, Missing}}`.

```
import Base: +, broadcast, Broadcast.broadcast_c, Broadcast.containertype;


broadcast(+, A::Array{Union{T, Missing}}, B::Array{T}) where {T<:Number} =
        broadcast_c(+, containertype(A, B), A, B) |> Array{Union{T, Missing}};

broadcast(+, A::Array{T}, B::Array{Union{T, Missing}}) where {T<:Number} =
    broadcast_c(+, containertype(A, B), A, B) |> Array{Union{T, Missing}};

broadcast(+, A::Array{Union{T, Missing}}, B::Array{Union{T, Missing}}) where {T<:Number} =
    broadcast_c(+, containertype(A, B), A, B) |> Array{Union{T, Missing}};
```

As mentioned, this is not a problem for Julia `0.7+`, but it is for `0.6.4`.